# Opensc in android

Tags: android, smartcard, android-bluetooth, pkcs#11, opensc

Softwares(such as Mozilla Firefox, Thunderbird) can load opensc module(opensc-pkcs11.so on linux and opensc-pkcs11.dll on windows)and use all smart cards supported by OpenSC for authentication, signing and decryption. My question is how can we do the same thing in android(where to store opensc module, how to access an external token etc.). For example how can an application use opensc module to access a smartcard token with nfc and/or bluetooth interface.

I dont like to flash my android like in seek for android. 
I request for any suggestions or examples. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi , did you resolve this ? Did you use openSC ?